# With Java String, is "full expected text".equals("full expected text") faster than "full expected text".contains("expected")?

Tags: java, string, performance

Assuming that anytime a string contains "expected", you know the full string will always be "full expected text", is it faster in an "if" condition to do String.equals("full expected text") or String.contains("expected")?

I'm just curious if the algorithm that determines whether two strings are equal, from beginning to end, is simpler than the algorithm that looks for a substring, and if so, is it sometimes faster to just do the equals comparison than only looking for a substring. I'm guessing if contains() is sometimes faster, it depends on the length of the substring and perhaps the length of the full string.

Comment: *Beware premature optimizations.* To fully determine which is faster, you need to profile the code using real life examples. But, the performance difference is likely so small that you're wasting time that would be much better spent elsewhere. Only try to optimize this if profiling your code shows that this piece of code consumes excessive CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, equality is a cheap operation that is easy to implement quickly, whereas finding substrings is a diverse field with lots of trade-offs and generally a lot of overhead that is hard to remove entirely. In theory, the two algorithms may perform similarly on a fast-path when the input and output match, but there are many more fast paths for equality and certain searches are unavoidably slow in several common cases, like when the potential substring is not an inhabitant of a much longer string.

This is not about ‘premature optimization’, this is about using the correct algorithm. The claims that you can't make performance judgements about things this obvious without profiling are rather baffling.

Answer (score 5):

First, always write your code on the basis of what's easier to read and understand; the tiny computational efficiency will be swamped by the developer effort required to figure out anything overly clever.

That said, a comparison in the case of a match will always be at least O(m) on the size of the pattern to be matched, and a character-by-character comparison is as cheap as you can get. In the *failure* case, this approach just exits as soon as it finds a mismatch; the *worst-case* is O(m) (and the only state required is a single integer index).

[Substring algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Single-pattern_algorithms), on the other hand, may have to backtrack repeatedly if, for example, your searched string were `expecteexpecteexpecte`. These algorithms are pretty universally *much* more expensive than O(m) (usually at least O(m+n)). Unless your "full string" is *dramatically* longer, then I would expect the simple `equals` to be the faster choice as well as a better match for the intended meaning.

Comment: "Make it correct, make it clear, make it concise, make it fast. In that order." - Wes Dyer, C# compiler developer